# window.onpopstate is not working; nothing happens when I navigate back to page

Tags: javascript, history, popstate

I'm trying to add `window.onpopstate` on one of the pages on my site, but nothing is happening. I put this script on the page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    if (event.state) {
      alert(event.state);
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

I have also tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onpopstate = function() {
    alert("popped!");
  }
</script>
```

However, I don't get any alerts when I navigate back to the page.

Comment: I found a really good and detailed explanation of the `popstate` event at https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/events-popstate-event.

Answer (score 34):

You get a `popstate` event only if you add one or more history entry/entries and later the user clicks the **back** button in the browser.

Adding entries to the browser history lets you change the URL (just as the user navigates to another page) but without actually loading a new page.

You add a history entry with `pushState` method:

```
history.pushState({}, '', '/newpage');
```

As you add one entry and the user clicks **back** the URL switches back to the previous one but the page at that address is not loaded. A `popstate` event is triggered instead.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

---

**Exceptions:**

Older browsers don't support `popstate` events and manipulation of the browser's history.

Some browsers (ex. Safari) trigger a `popstate` event also when the page is actually loaded.

Comment: lets say i write `window.addEventListener('popstate', (e) => console.log(e))` in the chrome devtools console, how would i see console log after i've clicked back button?

Comment: @AkinHwan popstate is only triggered when you're moving from a pushedState to a previous state (or something like that..).  If you're navigating from a separate page back to the first page, it won't trigger.

Comment: so are you saying that if i have "http://localhost/page.html#1234" loaded and then I *manually* enter "http://localhost/page.html#5678" to load basically the same page, and then click the back button, onpopstate *won't* get called *even though* it's the same identical page?

Comment: this was the missing piece for me. I was trying to close a mobile nav with the browser's back button but popstate was never triggered. what I did was, whenever the nav was opened, set a local var `_navIsOpened = true` and push a new history state `history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);` to keep me on the same page and on using the back button, if `_navIsOpened` stay on same page with same new push to history state  or else go back with `history.back()` ✌️✌️✌️

Comment: You might also check this simple process out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512244/back-button-does-not-allow-re-selection-in-dropdown-select

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert(`location: ${document.location}, state: ${JSON.stringify(event.state)}`)
}

history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1")
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2")
history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3")
history.back() // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=1, state: {"page":1}"
history.back() // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html, state: null"
history.go(2)  // alerts "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=3, state: {"page":3}"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone facing this issue in React-JS,

let's say you have a useEffect() and want to log the popState on every re-render or (Go-Forward/Go-Back)

```
 useEffect(() => {
    function handlePopStateEvent(e) {
        console.log(e);
        console.log("Check if the function Working")

    }

    console.log("Check if Effect Working")

    window.addEventListener("popstate", handlePopStateEvent);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("popstate", handlePopStateEvent);

}, []);
```

You will need to add some history manually using the history.pushState(), even if you did it by hand let's say you typed in the URL some routes/paths like

> http://localhost:5173/lab

> http://localhost:5173/home

> http://localhost:5173/blog

> http://localhost:5173/about

it will not work, the popState() event will not log anything, and if you try to invoke the function manually to see the log you will get undefined.

The solution: in the Console add some history like this:

> history.pushState({}, '', '/home');

> history.pushState({}, '', '/blog');

> history.pushState({}, '', '/about');

> history.pushState({}, '', '/lab');

[image: Add history to the browser manullay using history.pushState() in the console]

Then when you use the Back/Forward arrows in the browser or Alt + (← →) the popState() will log in to the console like this

[image: Logging the popState event in the console on Fowrard/Back]

On every Back/Forward.

For more understanding of this behavior, you can check the MDN on the History API, popState, and history.push()

Here's the Mdn description:

> The popstate event of the Window interface is fired when the active
> history entry changes while the user navigates the session history. It
> changes the current history entry to that of the last page the user
> visited or, if history.pushState() has been used to add a history
> entry to the history stack, that history entry is used instead.

Link: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_eve](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)nt