# Clearing drop-down select value on page exit so back button return may reselect

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am, basically, answering the question here, but perhaps someone has another idea. You can use an onpopstate function, but I find this much simpler to deal with and cross-browser compatible, even with old browsers.

I have a drop-down select box that is populated by a database query. In this case, it has only found one relevant city. Selecting that city, which takes the user to another page, then pressing the Back button, returns the user to the page with the selection still in the selected state, which prevents it from being selected again, unless another selection is made first. So I added an onClick event to change the Selected default before leaving the page.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <select class="DropList"  name="CitySelect" id="CitySelect"
        onchange="if(options[selectedIndex].value){location = options[selectedIndex].value}"
        onclick="GetSelect()">
        <option value="" selected>Select City</option>
        <option value="city.php?s=Montana&cn=Yellowstone&CalNav=0&c=Billings">Billings</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSelect()
    {
        document.getElementById('CitySelect').value = "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listening for the click event is not ideal for a couple of reasons:

- It's triggered when you click the select to open it, not when you actually select an option. So your code clears the value when you open the select which results in a bit of jerkiness.
- It's not triggered if you use the keyboard to select a value.

So I'd instead suggest using the blur event:

```
$('#CitySelect').on('blur', (e) => (e.target.value = ''));
```

Immediately after selecting the value, the select field will still have the new value but as soon as you leave the field ("blur" it), the value will reset.

Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/td6zvjur/)

Comment: Point well taken on using blur. I ended up just replacing onclick with onblur, which works fine. I could not get your example to work as-is. Running jQuery 1.10 on this project right now, but even when I augmented your code, it did not work for me. Not exactly sure why. Could have something to do with the way I populate my Selects, which is using a PHP function I wrote with a bunch of parameters. I assume that simply changing onclick to onblur in my example will work fine. Don't see any problems. Your thoughts?.

Comment: Actually, I found that onblur, for whatever reason, did not work in Edge and, I assume, in other webkit browsers, so I went back to onclick. Since, I assume, the onclick event will occur before an onblur, perhaps that is the problem. I don't experience the problems you mention using onclick.